# Which mathematical property explains this Matrix operation

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

[Output of that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CY3.png)
My Question is not about python code, but related to linear algebra or Matrix properties(like additive, distributive)

How to explain the following operation mathematically

```
X = X0 append/Concat X1  
(X.Transpose Multiply X) result same of (X0.Transpose Multiply X0) + (X1.Transpose Multiply X1)
```

here X1 is appended to X0 then and stored in X, then multiplied X with X transpose. the result is the same as
(X0.T Multiply X0) + (X1.T Multiply X1)
I gave the python code snippets of that to execute and see.
So, I am trying to understand, how I can explain it with linear Algebra or Matrix multiplication properties.

```python
import numpy as np
X0 = np.array([[1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
              ])
X1 = np.array([   [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  ])
X = np.array([   [1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
    [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  ])

W_t = (X.T @ X)


W0 = (X0.T @ X0) 
W1 = (X1.T @ X1) 

W = W0 + W1
print(W-W_t)
```

Comment: what's your question? is it about the `@` operator? It's a matrix multiplication operator introduced in python 3.5 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am interested in which matrix property explains that..not in python code

Comment: This question seems to be about linear algebra, but Stack Overflow is about _programming_

Comment: What do you mean by "which matrix property explains the operation"? Its just an operation using dot products and element-wise addition of some matrices. easy to follow whats going on. its unclear what you want to know about the matrix operations you have described. If you want to know why the output matrix is all zeroes, just run each code snippet step by step. Also, just to clarify `(X0.T @ X0)` is not `(X.T Multiply X)`, instead it is `(X0.T Dot_product X0)`

Comment: If you mean multiplying a matrix by it's transpose... this might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special